# iptables: POSTROUTING rule not matching with mark

Tags: networking, iptables

I have a host that sends packets to virtual machine say on 192.168.0.1/24 with either 192.168.0.11 or 192.168.0.12 as the destination IP. I'm trying to set up the virtual machine as a NAT. It routes the packets, changing the destination IP, depending on the original destination IP so I wasn't able to only use SNAT as the original IP was getting switched in PREROUTING. What I've been trying to use is the --set-mark flag to flag the packets with either 11 or 12 so the POSTROUTING rules will know what SNAT rule to use. Here are my rules:

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING --destination 192.168.0.11 -j MARK --set-mark 11
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -m mark --mark 11 -i eth0 -j DNAT --to 20.0.21.11
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -m mark --mark 11 -o eth1 -j SNAT --to-source 20.0.1.1
```

and

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING --destination 192.168.0.12 -j MARK --set-mark 12
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -m mark --mark 12 -i eth0 -j DNAT --to 20.0.21.11
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -m mark --mark 12 -o eth1 -j SNAT --to-source 20.0.1.2
```

My first two rules are being incremented if I watch iptables -t mangle/nat -nvL but the POSTROUTING rule never gets matched. Any ideas on why this would be?

I just thought of this while writing this. The first network is /24 subnet and I have then second network currently set up as a /8 subnet. Would this affect this in any way?

**EDIT**

To make things a little more clear.

This first step is the host sends either 192.168.0.11/24 or 192.168.0.12/24 from 192.168.0.1/24 to the virtual machine like so.

```
                     Destination IPs
     HOST           ================
===============  +--* 192.168.0.11 *--+  ======
* 192.168.0.1 *---  ================  ---* VM *
===============  +--* 192.168.0.12 *--+  ======
                    ================
```

I then want the virtual machine to forward these packets with both of the destination IP changed to 20.0.21.11/8. Then have the source IP change to either 20.0.21.1/8 or 20.0.21.2/8 depending on what the original destination IPs were. Like so.

```
            Source IPs w/ 20.0.21.11 as Destination IP 
           ==============
======  +--* 20.0.21.1 *--+   ============
* VM *---  ==============  ---* Test rig *
======  +--* 20.0.21.2 *--+   ============
           ==============
```

Also to be clear this is a NAT on a private network. There is no internet connection here. Just `Host <--> VM <--> Test rig`

**EDIT 2**

One more drawing to make it a little more clear.

```
                  Destination IPs     Source IPs
     HOST         ==============    ===============        Test rig
=============  +--*192.168.0.11*-+  |   20.0.21.1 *--+  ==============
*192.168.0.1*---  ============== +--* VM          |  +--* 20.0.21.11 *
=============  +--*192.168.0.12*-+  |   20.0.21.2 *--+  ==============
                  ==============    ===============
```

Comment: What exactly is your topology? Outside world <-> <192.168.0.0/24> <-><20.0.1.0/XX>?

Comment: Host <-> VM <-> Test PC. See the 'EDIT' I made.

Comment: It does not really matter if its connected to the internet or not. So all requests come from 192.168.0.1 or it is acting as a gateway between 192.168.0/24 and some other network and forwarding packets?

Comment: The VM is forwarding packets. It's purpose is to act as a simulator for networking traffic to change packets for the test rig as they would be in the field. Forwarding what's coming out of the host (where lab tools are located) to the test rig.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rules look right, check if you have bridges setup, these can make packet's in/out interfaces to be messed up.
You can also add -j LOG rules to watch what gets matched in your logs.

Comment: I'm not sure if I have a gateway but I could be wrong. I want a VM on the host to 'simulate' packets for a test rig by forwarding packets from the host to the test rig. See the EDIT I made above.

Comment: My issue is this. I can't use just SNAT and DNAT because the outgoing source depends on the incoming destination (from the point of view of the VM). This is because the incoming destination was changed in PREROUTING and now we want to determine the outgoing source in POSTROUTING based on the incoming destination. That's why I started looking into marking the packets when they arrive so I can match them on their way out. This match on the way out is not catching any packets.

Comment: Yes, but that's what connection tracking is for. Its tracking each connection and remembers how it was NAT'ed and when packets come on this connection it knows how to handle them. Checkout /proc/net/ip_conntrack

Comment: Connection tracking as in using conntrack?

Comment: Oh just saw the /proc/net/ip_conntrack. Ok I will. My understanding was that conntrack is just for tracking packets as in counting how many times it sees a certain packet. Will connmark work in this case or no?

Comment: Whenever you use NAT connection tracking gets enabled automatically. Thats how it works.

Comment: From http://linux-ip.net/html/nat-dnat.html: To enable DNAT, at least one iptables command is required. The connection tracking mechanism of netfilter will ensure that subsequent packets exchanged in either direction (which can be identified as part of the existing DNAT connection) are also transformed.

Comment: That sounds like it's talking about packets coming from the test rig going to the host. As in if you create a rule to forward 192.168.0.11 packets to 20.0.21.11 then packets going from 20.0.21.11 will be forwarded to 192.168.0.11. And not dealing with the two separate flows I want with 192.168.0.11 and 192.168.0.12.

Comment: Well, thats why you make 2 rules for matching 11 and 12.

Comment: Actually you don't even need NAT in your case. If its just two networks you can get away with simple static routes.

Comment: `ip route add 192.168.0.0/24 dev eth1; ip route add 20.0/8 dev eth0` If you have ip address from each network on your middle(gateway) host on each interface those routes should be added autimatically. So the only thing you need is `ip addr add 192.168.0.2/24 dev eth0; ip addr add 20.0.0.1/8 dev eth0` and you should be good to go.

Comment: I'm not sure this will change the destination and source IP will it? Which is critical for the test rig.

Comment: Why do you need to change the addresses?

Comment: For simulating the test rig as it would be in the field. It's a safety critical system and has very high regulations. It will not accept packets if the source and destination IPs are not an exact match.

Comment: Plus a certain agency won't accept a solution to testing the rig if it's not exactly like it would be in the field.

Comment: Is this PCI DSS certification? Well forget about the routing then, try out the rules in the answer and see if they work.

Comment: DO-178B is our guideline.

Comment: I guess I don't understand this rule.
`iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 20.0.1.1 -o eth1 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.0.11`. It's matching the packet with a source of 20.0.1.1? No packet will match this will it?

Comment: From the link you provided they have these two rules `[root@real-server]# iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 205.254.211.17 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.100.17
[root@real-server]# iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.100.17 -j SNAT --to-destination 205.254.211.17`. Can you specify/change the destination IP in POSTROUTING with SNAT like this?

Comment: Okay, now I get what you are trying to do. you can match -d -s yes

Comment: You can't change destination AND source in POSTROUTING though can you? Is my thinking that marking the packets in PREROUTING and then matching the packet with that mark in POSTROUTING incorrect? Or should this work? I made another edit to hopefully make the flow from the host to the test rig a little more clear.

Comment: Well, this is much more clearer, now your rules seem totally right. Check if in and out interfaces are set right. If you have bridges these can be messed up.

Comment: I didn't have ipv4 forwarding enables and now I'm seeing the POSTROUTING rule being incremented! HA! I'm going to go test it out. Thank you for your help and confirming my rules are correct. Starting to feel more confident with this now.

Comment: Ohh, I was thinking to ask about this yesterday but I thought its too obvious to be it ;)

Comment: Hahaha shoot. I'm guessing I'll need rules for going from the test rig to the host then too right? Just tried it out and the test rig isn't receive any packets. I can ping it from the VM. Looks like I'll be debugging this a little more.

Comment: You mean you cant connect from test rig to outside? If its that you can fix it with another -s 20.0.21.11-j SNAT to source 192.168.0.11 or 12. This should do it.

Comment: I can't remember what this issue was but I have it all working now. To people reading this post I must suggest doing a ping test before and after you set up iptable rules. A failed ping test after you set up rules will point you towards a mistake you made in the rules. Make sure you have ipv4 forwarding enabled and if you are specifying an interface make sure it is the correct interface. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Have you enabled IP forwarding on the host? If not then your second rules will never get matched because forwarded packets will be ignored by the kernel.

You can check with a `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`. If the output is zero, you can try `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` to see if that solves your problem. If so, `echo net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1 >> /etc/sysctl.conf` will make the setting survive a reboot.

I wanted to make this a comment but my reputation was too small. Sorry to post such an obvious answer but this has caught me out so many times that it's worth posting!

Comment: I myself have missed this many times